# Rails - Events fully booked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, paypal

I'm building an events app using Rails. I've installed a code block in my controller to ensure that over-booking doesn't occur once the total number of spaces for the event have been allocated/booked. 
The issue is that it only seems to work after the payment has been taken rather than before. I need the code to bring up a flash message when the user clicks on book the event but, at present, it allows the user to go through the payment process, takes their money AND THEN when it redirects back to the event page the flash message pops up. 
It also only works for paid events and not free events.

Here's my bookings_controller code -

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
        #@total_amount = @booking_quantity.to_f * @event_price.to_f

    end

    def create
        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f

        Booking.transaction do

            @event.reload
            if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
            flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
            end 
        end

        if @booking.save

            # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
            # #{} == puts a variable into a string
            Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
                card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end

        if @event.is_free?

            @booking.save!
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        end
    end

    #def total_amount
        #@total_amount = @booking.quantity * @event.price
    #end

    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
    end

end
```

Can this be adjusted in the controller or does it need a method in the model?

Comment: At the moment your transaction block ends after  the if block. Is this a copy paste error or is this realy your actual code?

Comment: This is the actual code.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `if` statement **before** the Booking transaction block? In my opinion, only call the Booking transaction if the event spaces is available and not after.

Answer (score 0):

Rails advocates fat models and slim controllers. With this in mind you should pull your business logic out of the controller. You can put this code into your model.

It is possible that you extend your transaction until the end of your action. When some thing goes wrong you can raise an error and the transaction will be rolled back. If in some error cases payment is already done you have to handle / refound it.

But, your code suffers 2 race conditions. The first race condition occours from the time some one was send to paypal and comes back. In this time a second customer can have booked and paid an event and it's not allowed to book this event any more when the second customer comes back from paypal. This can be a long time period and you should refound your customer.

The second race condition starts here `if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces` this statement can be `false`for multiple requests at the same time. Even when only one booking is left. In this case you end up with more bookings as you want.

Comment: Do I apply the transaction code block in the bookings model, then or is it different logic? How do I go about doing this in the model?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @slowjack2k FYI, you can get magic links by doing `[sitename.se]`, e.g. `[codereview.se]` turns to [codereview.se] =)